# What is the general decomposition method to find stationary distribution of a transition matrix in Markov Chain?

Tags: markov-chains, matrix-decomposition

Based on the definition of transition matrix in Wikipedia, I assume that it is not symmetric but is it always diagonalizable? The solution is written using eigen decomposition. How if it is not diagonalizable? Will it be solved using singular value decomposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the transition matrix of a Markov chain is a stochastic matrix that is not diagonalizable in general. The [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) asserts that if the matrix is irreducible, there is a unique probability invariant vector associated to the largest eigenvalue.

So for example you compute the characteristic polynomial, take its largest eigenvalue $\lambda$ and solve the equation $Px = \lambda x$ to find a vector with non-negative coordinates. You then divide by the sum of its coordinates to get a probability vector.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. So the theorem doesn't limit the matrix to be diagonalizable, but I need to make sure that the probability vector is different from orthonormal vector, right?

Comment: Okay, I understand. The objective of Markov Chain problem is to solve $Px = \lambda x$ while in singular value decomposition the objective is to factorize $P$ to $U \Sigma V^T$. It is different.